# How to get element in eventContent of FullCalendar v5 and to assign it to tip?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I move into FullCalendar v5 from v4 and I try to set hints for any cell.
In v4 I used eventRender like:

```
            eventRender: function (eventInfo) {
                let external_google_calendar_button = ""
                if (eventInfo.event.url != "" && typeof eventInfo.event.url != "undefined") {
                    // alert( eventInfo.event.url + "  eventInfo.event..url ::"+( typeof eventInfo.event.url )  )
                    external_google_calendar_button = '<i class=\'fa fa-external-link\' style=\'color:#eaeaea;\' title=\'Has event at Google Calendar\'></i>&nbsp;';
                }
                let adTooltipHtml = '..."

                let editorBtnHTML= '<button type="button" class="action_btn m-0 mr-1 p-0 px-1" @click.prevent="openAdCard( \'' + eventInfo.event.id + '\' )" title="Open ad card">+</button>'


                eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-content').innerHTML = '<span class="flex flex-nowrap">'+editorBtnHTML +  eventInfo.el.querySelector('.fc-content').innerHTML + '</span>'

                tippy(eventInfo.el, {
                    content: adTooltipHtml,
                    allowHTML: true,
                    animation: 'fade',
                    delay: 100,
                    duration: 100,
                });
```

Here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks I read :

> eventContent - a Content Injection Input. Generated content is
> inserted inside the inner-most wrapper of the event element. If
> supplied as a callback function, it is called every time the
> associated event data changes.

and I try to use eventContent event for the same goal :

```
eventContent: function (eventInfo) {
    console.log('eventContent eventInfo::')
    console.log(eventInfo)
    console.log('eventInfo.event::')
    console.log(eventInfo.event)
```

But I failed to get access to element to set hint to it.
What I see in browser's console : https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0aH4.jpg

How to get element I have to assign tip ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I failed to  get access to element

...yes because as per the [content injection documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection) you don't get access to it directly. You simply `return` the HTML you want to put within it, without any need to know anything about the element you're injecting into.

However that's not really what you're trying to do here - you're trying to attach a tooltip to the whole element.

Again as per the [event render hooks documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks), if you use the `eventDidMount` callback instead, this gives you access to the `el` property within the supplied data, which represents the element.